# Can anyone help identify this turbine blade?

Tags: jet-engine, military, feature-identification

At the local army/navy surplus store and found this in a "junk" box. Got it for $1. Would live to know what airframe this came off of. Im new to this so compressor blade? Compressor turbine?

Markings:
Written in sharpie 8740

Engraved 8740 (Hand engraved on bottom)

Stamped 6205DJ92

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Unlikely 8740 steel low alloy. That could only be used in the temperatures on the first few stages of the compressor inlet.

Comment: Maybe not an aircraft engine at all. Gas turbines are used in many places other than aircraft. The Abrams M1 tank used a gas turbine. Many military ships use them for extra power. The plant that generates electricity for your home uses steam turbines.

Comment: Good call on the abrams. Was also thinking perhaps due to the overall LACK of markings, inspections stamps etc that perhaps this is an APU. Ill expand my search. Thanks!